# Clarification of my understanding of .NET and C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, runtime

Can you guys tell me if my understanding is correct? I used to think .NET was a language before ever looking it up. Then, after reading some sites that I found out it was a framework, which at the time I thought was like a template of some sort for applications. Now I find out it's a runtime (is that like a JVM?), and an application framework library (What is that in simple terms?).

When they say .NET languages, what do they mean? Like languages that run on the .NET runtime(CLR)? So, C# and VB, which are .NET languages (I think), only work on Windows Machines or other machines that have CLR? Because then, whats the WinRT then?

"All programs written for the .NET framework, regardless of programming language, are executed by the CLR." --- I thought CLR was part of the .NET framework, so what do they programs written for the .NET framework?

I apologize for the huge mass of questions, but it's very confusing to me, but I haven't taken any OS or compiler design courses yet, so maybe that's why.

Maybe this is too broad, but all the questions are linked together, so it wouldn't make sense if I ask separately.

in addition to what you've all said, I found a great website in relevance to this:

Does.NET_run_only_on_Windows">http://tutorials.csharp-online.net/CSharp_FAQ:*Does*.NET_run_only_on_Windows

^^^for people that look at this question in future

Comment: This will probably be closed as too broad, but here's a few tidbits:

.NET languages run on the CLR. The standard Microsoft implementation works on Windows, but an open-source implementation exists: Mono. Mono can run on Windows, OS X and Linux.

Comment: Did you try [what is the .NET Framework](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+the+.net+framework)? It found me this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework.

Comment: But all the questions are linked together, so it wouldn't make sense if I ask separately.

Comment: No, but a little searching online would answer all questions at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word .NET is a marketing term that has been used to cover many things. However, the .NET Framework is more concrete. It is, as the name suggests, a framework consisting of many things.

- The CLR (Common Language Runtime) which is a VM that complies with a standard Microsoft released called the [CLI](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) (Common Language Interface). This is comparable to Java's JVM.
- CIL (Common Intermediate Language) also known as IL or MSIL, which is the language that the CLR runs. Comparable to Java's bytecode.
- The .NET Framework standard libraries.

Now to run things using the .NET Framework you need languages that target it (or otherwise code in CIL). These languages are usually called .NET languages. Most famous of them are C# and VB.NET, but others exist such as F# and IronPython. When compiled (or interpreted) code in these languages becomes CIL code which the CLR runs.

Note that the .NET Framework is just *one* implementation of the CLI standard. Mono is another compatible implementation that is open sourced and multi platform.

Comment: ok thank you, i think I got it now. but one last question; what does it mean "All programs written for the .NET framework, regardless of programming language, are executed by the CLR."? Programs written for windows or anything using the .net? because the CLR is part of .net

Comment: Yes, all programs *targeting* the .NET Framework are executed by the corresponding CLR virtual machine.

Comment: ok thank you, I don't understand why the last time I read the wiki page on it and other sites, that I didn't understand it then.

Answer (score 1):

All that languages like C#, F#, VB.net and much more languages are compiled to a CIL (Common Intermediate Language) which is interpreted by the .net framework.

So this code is in general portable if you don't use native APIs. If you use them you can also make them portable but this is a little more complex but possible! In my application I put the differnt platform dll files in multiple directories which where all im my local path variable.

However you can use that code also for Linux and Mac by using Mono a .net port for Unix like systems. But you need to recompile your application when you use mono.

Answer (score 1):

.NET is a framework which consists of many libraries and a compiler. Their are a couple different compilers for .NET that include support for both C# and VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

You can use C#, VB.NET, Iron Python among others to program using the .NET Framework. Once you compile the code, it turns into an intermediate language code, this code can be interpreted by CLR on Windows machines by standard and by some others via Mono framework (this IS similar to JVM).